# Logging in jclouds still prints retry connection error to console, with credentials

Tags: java, logback, openstack, jclouds, devstack

Have two issues with this message.

**Info**: using a local vm with openstack's devstack; icehouse version. Using 1.8.0 of jclouds.

1. I am trying to configure the logger with jclouds and keep getting an
   error message print out to the console. But I keep getting this
   error to surface in my main program. I originally was using
   the [NullLogger](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/d57bbebe7e0217b9a3818c6e1ed460c90469da78/core/src/main/java/org/jclouds/logging/NullLogger.java#L32-L39) but found that errors still get printed. Created
   my own NullLogger that would not print errors, and am still getting
   this issue (just overrode the error functions)
2. Another problem is that this message just spits out the credentials used to try to connect. I would like to at least catch this message before it got printed and just mention that it couldn't connect to the server.

Any ideas to fix either of these would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks.

Specfic error>>>>>>>

> 2015-02-10 10:56:36.707 ERROR [Thread-5]
>   o.j.h.h.BackoffLimitedRetryHandler Cannot retry after server error,
>   command has exceeded retry limit 5:
>   [method=org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.AuthenticationApi.public
>   abstract org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.domain.Access
>   org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.AuthenticationApi.authenticateWithTenantNameAndCredentials(java.lang.String,org.jclouds.openstack.keystone.v2_0.domain.PasswordCredentials)**[admin,
>   PasswordCredentials{username=admin, password=openstack}]**, request=POST
>   http://xxxxxx:5000/v2.0/tokens HTTP/1.1]

logback.xml>>>>>>

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>jclouds.log</file>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%thread] %logger{10} %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: What code did you use to configure a custom NullLogger?

Comment: I created my own logger that did not do anything for the error functions; also implemented from Logger. Also made my own NullLoggerModule that extended from LoggingModule for the createLoggerFactory. I could provide a code-link, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question, you can try to configure a [Logback filter](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) to print only the messages in the levels you configure.

The second one would require changes in the jclouds code, as that password is shown because the [PasswordCredentials](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/apis/openstack-keystone/src/main/java/org/jclouds/openstack/keystone/v2_0/domain/PasswordCredentials.java#L130) object prints it in the `toString` method. That method could be changed to just print `*****` instead of the clear text password. Feel free to raise a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS) issue for this if you need it.

Comment: Thank you. I will bring it up but do you think I could override that class/method that prints out the password? Injection?

Comment: Unfortunately you won't be able to do that, as that class in not created by the Guice injector.